# Spring boot controller path extend another path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

We have an application with path pattern like this:

`/{language}/{subsystem}/blah/blah`

the `language` and `subsystem` variable will do some common logic and apply to all 100+ controllers, i wanna ask instead of repeating this common logic 100 times in each controller, is there a way to define a centralized controller like

`/{language}`

which is to handle the language logic and another centralized controller like

and `/{subsystem}`

which is to handle the subsystem logic and all other controller kinda of '**extend**' from these controllers ?
Hope i describe it clearly. many thanks and happy weekend:)

Comment: What kind of logic set with '/language'? I'm not sure but if you just want to remove redundant call of same type URL then use 'nginx' kind of tool which helpful for URL bifurcation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think about writing a [custom Interceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-interceptors) for your application. This interceptor could fetch the `language` and `subsystem` parts from your URL path and invoke your common logic in a central place.

There are a few pitfalls to this approach that you should balance carefully:

1. it's very implicit - people might miss that your interceptor is in place and could be in for a surprise
2. it'll apply for all incoming requests - if you want it to skip certain requests, you have to implement this logic within the interceptor

Personally, I'd take another approach and go for a combination of [`@RequestMapping` and `@PathVariable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) annotations on every controller method to capture `language` and `subsystem` and put the common logic into a helper method:

```java
@GetMapping("/{language}/{subsystem}/something")
public String doSomething(@PathVariable Language language, @PathVariable Subsystem subsystem) {
    LanguageSubsystemHelper.doSomething(language, subsystem);
    // ...
}
```

Reduce the repetition to a minimum by providing a helper that's available for all controller methods. The benefits of this approach are:

1. you have granular control when to use or not use the common logic
2. it's explicit
3. you can automatically validate `language` and `subsystem` by binding the path variables to an enum